# Overlay a TikZ node into an mdframed

Tags: mdframed, tikz-node, anchor

I'd like to place a small piece of text at the upper right of an mdframed box that I'm using to display source code for a program.

Here's what I have tried:

```
\begin{mdframed}
\begin{minted}{swift}
print("Hello")
print("World")
for i in 0..<10 {
    print(i)
}
\end{minted}
\end{mdframed}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]%
\node[anchor=north east,inner sep=5pt,fill=black] at (current page.north east) {\textcolor{white}{Swift}};
```

This causes the little black box with the word "Swift" to be rendered to the top right of the *page*, but I'd like it rendered inside the frame box. I've also tried to place the tikz line inside the mdframed environment, but the same thing happens: the node shows up at the top right of the page.

If I replace `current page` with `current bounding box`, I don't see the node at all, and searching the rendered pdf for the text does not find it, so I'm not sure where it even went!

Am I missing something obvious? How do I get the tikz command to know to anchor the node to the mdframed environment?

Comment: Can you please turn your code fragment into a MWE? This checklist may assist you in doing so: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 . Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be easily achieved by using `tcolorbox`. It has build-in `minted` support. And it's more powerful and flexible than `mdframed`. Even though the [manual](https://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) looks a little bit complex but if you take some time to read, it is straightforward and can achieve a really nice look framed box.

Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[minted,skins]{tcolorbox}
\newtcblisting{mybox}[1][]{
enhanced jigsaw,
listing engine=minted,
listing only,
title=Swift,
minted language=swift,
sharp corners,
colframe=darkgray,
colback=yellow!40,
coltitle=red!70,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
boxrule=1pt,
attach boxed title to top right=
{yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight-1pt,xshift=-1pt},
boxed title style={enhanced jigsaw,colback=lightgray,boxrule=0pt,sharp corners},
#1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
print("Hello")
print("World")
for i in 0..<10 {
    print(i)
}
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}[title=LaTeX,minted language=latex,listing and text]
This is a default tcolorbox:
\begin{tcolorbox}
    example contents
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]